# how to change the iframe inside web page css

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

Made a simple step by step form in jquery HTML and tried to insert in to the wordpress site but some .js conflict and there was many errors.so planned to open the form inside a iframe.but the problem is i want to change the form theme accordions to the site theme color.is there any way to do this??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe refer this question

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/a/1639342/16959 however thee iframe must be on the same domain as the outer page.